# Image SRCSET selects bigger image instead of nearest matching image for higher DPR devices like iphone

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, srcset

What I am trying to achieve

| Breakpoints | Expected Image Width |
| --- | --- |
| Max-width 539 | 539 |
| Max-width 767 | 767 |
| Max-width 991 | 991 |
| Max-width 1199 | 1199 |
| Max-width 1440 | 1440 |
| Max-width 1920 | 1920 |

Issue: Devices with higher DPR are choosing bigger images instead of the nearest matching image
example: iPhone 12pro's screen is 1170, so the nearest matching image is 1199 but it downloads 1440 image for some reason.

POC LINK: https://responsiveimagepoc.netlify.app/

My Code :

```
<img class="image" style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="images/main.jpg" alt="" width="3840" height="1440"
srcset="images/Mobile539.jpg 539w, images/Tablet767.jpg 767w, images/Medium991.jpg 991w, images/Large1199.jpg 1199w, images/xlarge1440.jpg 1440w, images/default1920.jpg 1920w"
sizes="(max-width:539px)539px, (max-width:767px)767px, (max-width:991px)991px,(max-width:1199px)1199px,(max-width:1440px)1440px,1920px">
```

Comment: I would expect the sizes/srcset logic is intended to consider device pixel ratio, as with high DPR you can show the full detail of the image

Comment: Yes, But browsers do consider DPR while calculating device-width , For ex. iPhone 12pro's screen width is 390 but its DPR is 3 hence 390*3 = 1170 is considered as width, And with this width it should download 1199 image because it is nearest matching size But for some reason it chooses to download 1440

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that srcset/sizes is there to allow the developer to use as high a resolution image as the output device can benefit from.

To achieve what you're aiming for here (ignoring DPR), you could instead use something like this:

```css
.img {
  background-image: url('images/Mobile539.jpg');
}
@media (min-width: 540px) { 
  background-image: url('images/Tablet767.jpg'); }
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  background-image: url('images/Medium991.jpg'); }
/* ... */
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But i am looking for solution that would work with img tag